# Bash: Adding 1 to serial counter in a named.conf file, how is it done?

Tags: bash, dns, escaping

I have a script which updates DNS records on a DNS server. Every time the `named.conf` file is updated with a new site I have to raise the serial counter by at least 1.
So my scripts is running on a remote machine and I'm about to add the next line:

```
serial=`ssh root@172.19.214.X 'cat /var/named/named.booking.zone |grep serial |awk -F\" \" '{print $1}''`
```

It doesn't work well, I think i'm not escaping the `""` correctly...
And then I thought of something like that:

```
ssh root@172.19.214.X "sed -e 'g/"$serial"/"$serial"+1/s' /var/named/named.booking.zone"
```

My source file:

```
$TTL    600
@               IN SOA  root. booking.local. (
                                        2013030311      ; serial (d. adams)
                                        604800          ; Refresh
                                        86400           ; Retry
                                        2419200         ; Expire
                                        604800 )        ; Minimum
;

                        IN MX           10 mail
                        IN NS           dns
                        IN A            172.19.214.X
www                     IN A            172.19.214.X
```

Can you please show me how to do the escapes correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having this content for **/var/named/named.booking.zone** :

```
serial "1"
```

You can use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
serial=$(ssh root@172.19.214.X 'grep serial /var/named/named.booking.zone'  2>/dev/null |awk '{print $1}' )
(( next_serial = serial + 1 ))
ssh root@172.19.214.X 'sed -i.bak -e 's_${serial}_${next_serial}_g' /var/named/named.booking.zone'  2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns blank line and not the serial. I also tried to remove the `2>/dev/null` in order to see where it fails but i get the same blank line...

Comment: sorry for the late response, it gives me this error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`